# Application throws error after deploy on vm

Tags: linux, angular, npm, virtual-machine, angular-cli

I've got an application migrated from angular 2 to angular 5. When I deploy it locally and launch it via `http-server` I got no errors.

**The problem occurs when I deploy it on my vm**. After deployment when I open it in browser it throws the following errors:

> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>       at _isAndroid (forms.js:920)
>
> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>   TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>       at _isAndroid (forms.js:920)

The deploy process in vm is as follows:

1. Clone repository
2. Install npm packages
3. Build application via `angular-cli`
4. Copy distribution folder on the relative path

My machines (local and vm) have the exact same npm 5.8.0, @angular-cli 1.7.3 and I don't use `package-lock.json`.

Finally I have to mention that before migration I had this exact same deployment process working.

Do you know what's possibly going wrong ?

**Update**

What I came up with is a brand new vm initialization (os, node, etc.)

Comment: Curious, are you building with AoT in both local and vm?

Comment: No it's the default JiT

Comment: Maybe some package got updated and you've got a newer version on your vm? Try listing packages on both platforms and see the differences

Comment: @David I've tried cloning the repo and installing packages from scratch on my pc as well and I had no problems.

Comment: Did you compare the installed packages on both platforms? (`npm ls)`

Comment: Yes they are exact same

Comment: I got some **unmet peer dependency** errors though. They exist both locally and on vm, but local works fine even with the errors.

Comment: what is the `node -v` on both environments?

Comment: @ForestG On my pc it's `8.9.4`, on vm it's `6.12.0`

Comment: I think you should update to node v8+ on both just to be sure. Out of ideas apart from that :S

Comment: What if you serve it with ng serve instead?

Comment: Can you discover which file and line throws that error? I think kemsky would be on right track.

Comment: I'd say the file causing the issue is `node_modules/@angular/forms/esm5/forms.js`

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Object static methods are available in Node 6.x (well, not without a flag)
According to the Node website they are available in 7.x onwards.

See this [page](http://node.green/#ES2017-features-Object-static-methods) for details of the minimum version you need

As mentioned by ForestG, your best solution is to update your VM to Node 7.x or later.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like either minification issue due to missing `;` or aggressive optimization or file is corrupted, but difficult to reason without source code.

Example:

```
//without minification works ok
function test() {
      var postTypes = new Array('hello', 'there')   
      (function() { alert('hello there') })()
}

//after minification produces error Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
function test() {
      var postTypes = new Array('hello', 'there')(function() { alert('hello there') })()
}
```